# Is there a tool for merging fonts?

Tags: fonts

Is there a command-line tool that will replace a specified set of glyphs in one font with the corresponding glyphs in another font?

Comment: not really, and also any such tool would be specific to the font font formats being used. Are you asking about OpenType or classic TeX tfm+type 1 fonts or ....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, opentype.

Comment: ConTeXt supports fallback fonts if a non-LaTeX format is an alternative to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

The `unicode-math` package allows you to do this in math mode, with the `range=` option of `\setmathfont`. In text mode, a common way of doing this is to have `newunicodechar` make the character active and have it run a command that changes the font, e.g. for ☼:

```
\newunicodechar{^^^^263c}{{\symbolfont\symbol{"263C}}} % ☼
```

Another package that’s historically been used to do this was `ucharclasses`, but it was broken the last time I tested it.  With legacy fonts, `substitutefont` offers a way to replace all the characters in an 8-bit code page with a different font.